# How can I create 2 data.frame columns from a list of tuples?

Tags: r, dataframe, tuples

I have a list of tuples as output from my Python program and want to use R for some graphs of the data.

So from a python list of `[(1,2),(3,4),(0,9)]`, I want to come to a R `data.frame` of

```
x y
1 2
3 4
0 9
```

I just cant seem to find a simple way to do this.

Comment: What will be the input for R script? A string? Or what?

Comment: At the moment I simply print my python list to stdout, so a string i pipe to R probably, yes

Comment: How about turning it into an appropriate table in python, then storing as `feather` or csv and reading that into R?

Answer (score 0):

If the Input is a string you can try:

```
x="[(1,2),(3,4),(0,9)]"

x <- strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\(|\\)|\\]", "", x),",")[[1]]

cbind.data.frame(x=x[c(TRUE,FALSE)],y=x[c(FALSE,TRUE)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a numeric output, using strsplit...

```
inp <- "[(1,2),(3,4),(0,9)]"
out <- gsub("(^\\[\\()|(\\)\\]$)", "", strsplit(inp, "\\)\\,\\(")[[1]])
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(out, (function(el){
  as.numeric(strsplit(el, "\\,")[[1]])
})))
out
```

Result is

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    0    9
```